# How do I quickly move lots of files from one folder to another?

Tags: dropbox

I am trying to move files from my Camera uploads folder to another folder all within dropbox and using the web interface. This process is painfully slow taking about 30 minutes for just 100 photographs. Also if I select to lot which is a few thousand dropbox refuses to move them.

I have to do this because camera uploads which is synced to my PC is not too large for my hard drive on my PC.

Comment: How fast is your internet connection (upload)? Because you will obviously never be able to do this faster than that. Assuming the files are ~5 megabyte, uploading 100 files in 30 minutes would mean you have roughly 2 Mbit per second upload speed.

Comment: @Berend *all within dropbox and using the web interface*. I find it hard to believe that that goes through download/upload. It's more likely that these operations are throttled on the DropBox servers.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Comunity user 13 times.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem that you want to solve is that your hard drive is leaving out of free space. You think the solution is to move the files from one folder to another, but you are facing the problem of taking too much time.

A different approach might be more beneficial: instead of moving the files from one folder to another, set the files to be online only. For details, see [How to use Dropbox to save hard drive space](https://help.dropbox.com/sync/make-files-online-only), a help article from the [Dropbox Help Center](https://help.dropbox.com/).

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use the Dropbox sync, instead of Dropbox Web. It may still take a long time, but that way you can copy the whole lot and leave it going in the background.